# Fetch associated entities collection from Doctrine2 repository as an array

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, domain-driven-design

I'm starting a little project with DDD approach. I've created my domain model with Entities and ValueObjects in plain PHP. Entities have references to their associations - in my case, there is an `Employee` entity with collection of `Teams` he belongs to, and I keep them in `Employee::teams` property. Everything is going great, I've created mappings for those entities with associations in YAML, interfaces for repositories to be implemented in the Symfony2 and Doctrine2 layer, etc.

When I fetch `Employee`s from repository (with Doctrine's `EntityManager::findAll()`) instead of array of `Team`s I receive `PersistentCollection` with those teams. It's built on PHP7, and `Employee::getTeams()` has return type of `array` so I'm getting the critical exception.
Is there any way to convert it into array with some external listeners (Symfony layer only, to not to mess in domain files) or any other core mechanism?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the exception message you're getting ?

Comment: @Alok The exception is a PHP's `TypeError`: **Return value of Employee::getTeams() must be of the type array, object returned**. I know I could invoke `PersistentCollection::toArray()` but, if possible, I would like to avoid keeping such types in my domain because they suggest I'll be using Doctrine ORM (which includes the `PersistentCollection`)

Comment: Have you auto generated Entity? Because all onToMany associations have `\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection` return type.

Comment: No, I didn't. As I wrote at the beginning, first I wrote my whole domain logic and then I wanted to integrate it into Symfony mechanisms (DI container, Doctrine repositories, HTTP request handling, etc). My `Employee` class has `array` of `Team`s, while in the mapping, `teams` is in the `manyToMany` association.

Comment: Can you show your Employee class?

Comment: Here it is:
https://gist.github.com/eps90/de1e07a90a2be998076af3afdfe6604f

Comment: Try to change type of $teams from array to \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection.  You can use it like @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection.

Comment: Well, eventually it may be the only reasonable option.

Comment: Yeah if you want to follow the Symfony2 standards, it would be good idea to change it from array to collection.

Comment: I want to make my application business logic independent from any framework so I don't think Symfony2 standards make sense here. Btw. I think these are rather Doctrine2 standards :)

Comment: I have tried several approaches to implementing some of the DDD concepts using Doctrine ORM and have reached the conclusion that that ORM is simply not a good fit.  This array issue is merely the first of many annoyances you will encounter.  I dropped down to the Doctrine DBAL layer  and hand crafted my repositories.  Takes a bit of work but you end up with a very clean and performent system.

Comment: No one said DDD is the fastest way of developing applications :)

Comment: Opps. I mean Doctrine2 standards. :)

Comment: @KubaT using Doctrine Collections library is not such a bad idea. It's a separate small package and you're not making your domain depend on Doctrine ORM itself. I do such thing and I just cast it to array in getters (` return $collection->toArray()`), so it's not  possible to modify outside of the entity.

Comment: Yep, I've just done it that way. And you're right, Doctrine's Collection it's just a handy tool for make working with arrays easier and more verbose.

Comment: Actually, the reason Doctrine made it's own array is to provide the hooks for lazy loading.  Using it is not a bad idea but unless your domain actually needs it then you are building domain models based on persistence requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You get ArrayCollection
http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.5/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html

It has `toArray()` method so you can write

```
/**
 * @return Team[]
 */
public function getTeams(): array
{
    return $this->teams->toArray();
}
```

But I prefer

```
/**
 * @return Team[]|ArrayCollection
 */
public function getTeams()
{
    return $this->teams;
}
```

If you use good IDE like PhpStorm it will understand it correctly to autocomplete it like ArrayCollection and as `Team` if you make `foreach ($employee->getTeams() as $team) {...`

ArrayCollection are more powerful than plain arrays. For example you can filter and order them and Doctrine will make optimized SQL so you don't have to load all items
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections

Answer (score 0):

Kuba,

That doesn't seem to be a DDD question but a technical question regarding PHP implementation details.
However, please let me jump into your design and try to find a better solution for your domain. You are missing to model the relation between an employee and a team, let's call it employee in team. The way you did you are forcing an AR to reference another AR, saying this way that employee manages a team life cycle. This might not be the case but under a specific scenario another actor might change a status of a team and that could break the Employee invariant over the Team AR. Because of this when you make an AR to manage another AR life cycle then this dependency shouldn't be found through the repository and the root of the aggregate is in the position to now force invariant around the aggregated AR.
There are still some concerns to mention, but just to keep it simple, go ahead and model the concept you are missing: EmployeeInTeam or whatever you want to call it. It references the conceptual identity of the employee and the team so you can remove it safely in a future, you can query employees in a team and teams an employee is part of.
If you need frameworks or the DB to keep the consistence then you are not doing DDD. Use just objects, not the technology.

Regards,
Sebastian.

Comment: Sure, I didn't rely on any framework, as I said - I've built my domain model, implemented business logic and now I want to integrate it with Symfony to run with Doctrine for DB layer, Twig for displaying view, etc. Thank you for your constructive comment but I don't exactly get what did you mean by pointing this `EmployeeInTeam` object. What is it? And how should I use it?

Comment: EmployeeInTeam models the relation. If you read Vaugh Vernon about designing aggregate you would see employee::teams is not a good design decision.